# Likely-False Converse to Hölder Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

From the Hölder Inequality we know $\lVert fg\rVert_1\le \lVert f\rVert_p\lVert g\rVert_q$ whenever $p,q$ are conjugate. I expect the following (partial) converse is false:

> If $\lVert fg \rVert_1$ is finite then 
>   $\lVert f\rVert_p\lVert g\rVert_q$ is finite for some conjugate $p,q$

i.e. I do not expect the boundedness of $fg$ in $L^1$ to imply $f,g$ are in some conjugate $L^p$ spaces. I am not sure what a counter-example would look like though, since checking there is ***no*** choice of $p,q$ for which we get boundedness seems a daunting task. Is there a simple example I am missing?

Comment: You could have $f$ and $g$ supported on disjoint sets, so $fg=0$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So obvious in hindsight. Thank you for your example. Feel free to throw that up as an answer so I can close this out and sleep soundly knowing this is false.